# UISplitViewController - Tapping on cell in master view controller causes segue in master view controller and not in detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm working to migrate an existing project with a standard table view to use the UISplitViewController methodology.  The standard table view is also linked to a Tab Bar Controller.

The hierarchy is as follows:

Tab Bar Controller > SplitViewController > MASTER: NAVIGATION CONTROLLER > TABLE VIEW;

SplitViewController > DETAIL: Navigation Controller > TABLE VIEW;

When I tap on a cell in the master view controller, it causes a segue of the view I want loaded in the detail view area to be in the master view controller table view area. In essence, the detail view controller loads in the master view window area.

I've validated that all connections are made correctly, but I don't know why this is happening.  Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever got to the bottom of this or not but I just ran into the same issue and thought I'd explain how I fixed it incase anyone-else comes across it.

Basically make sure that the detail view controller is linked in your Split View Controller in the storyboard before linking the cells selection segue to the detail view controller.

Recreating the segue between the cell and the detail view controller was enough to fix this for me after I'd set the split view controller correctly.

Hope that helps,

Richard